# How to customize ionic style components (lists and tabs with different shapes)

Tags: css, ionic-framework, css-shapes

I was trying to customize ionic lists and tabs but since I am not too experienced in css does anyone know how to get these layouts ? :

List picture:

[image]

TABS picture:

[image]

Comment: please upload your images to imgur, as in their current format I personally can't see them and they can't be added to your question. Please further note you need to add your attempts so far. Cheers :)

Comment: This is CSS work. as said, paste your work in progress and issues

Comment: Well, I know that it is possible to achieve that with clip-path or background images with transparency. I just need tips from experienced devs :)

Comment: @jbutler483 , I hope now you can see the images :)

Comment: @PedroJusto: I have edited these in. Could you also add in your markup/attempts so far? I fear this, whilst interesting question, may be closed without any markup present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a border trick with some pseudo elements for this:

```css
.onecorner,
.twocorners {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.onecorner:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height:100%;
  width:25px;
  background:inherit;
  }
.onecorner:before,
.twocorners:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 0;
  height: 25px;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid lightgray;
}
.twocorners:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  width: 0;
  height: 25px;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="onecorner">tab 1</div>
<br/>
<div class="twocorners">tab 2</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much :)

what i'm doing is defining in my list-item this css properties:
 background-image: url(images/listItem.png); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;

wich kinda results but seems to me a very lame solution. your solution is great, I'll try do the same thing to the list items :)

Comment: for performance purposes , which is more advantageous? background image or pseudo elements? it is for a mobile webapp

Comment: @PedroJusto: pseudo elements would be (IMO) the way for this. Although, there would really be such a minimal difference anyway